# How can I obtain the date object from a timestamp in PHP?

Tags: php, date, time

How can I obtain the date object from a timestamp in PHP ?

e.g. `$timestamp = 1349938801;`

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind is createFromFormat:

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', '1349938801');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = new DateTime(); 
$date->setTimestamp($timestamp);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php